# Method of moments estimator, $P_\theta(X = x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$

Tags: estimators, method-of-moments

I am struggling with finding a method of moments estimator for (seemingly) simple situation:
pdf is given by $P_\theta(X = x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$,
$x \in$ {1,2,...$\theta$}, where $\theta \in N$.

My idea was to find the expectation and then, the first sample moment.
I did so far:

$E(x) = \int_{0}^{\theta}xf(x)dx$

$E(x) = \int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{1}{\theta}xdx$

$E(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}\int_{0}^{\theta}xdx$

$E(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}\int_{0}^{\theta}xdx$

$\frac{1}{\theta}$$\bigl|_{0}^{\theta}(\frac{x^2}{2})$

Applying the limits, I get:

$\frac{1}{\theta}(\frac{\theta^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2})$,

from which follow that:

$\bar{X} = \frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{1}{2\theta}$.

This does not seem like a correct answer, because the book provides MOM as:

$2\bar{X} -1$

But I cannot get the same MOM with the expectation I calculated. I admit that my expectation is wrong, or I misunderstand the further steps of calculation.

I would appreciate if someone can help!

Thank you!

Marina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a discrete distribution, so it does not have a density $f(x)$ but instead a probability mass function.  Its expectation is $$E[X]= 1 \times \frac1\theta + 2 \times \frac1\theta + \cdots + \theta \times \frac1\theta = \frac{\theta(\theta+1)}{2} \times \frac1\theta = \frac{\theta+1}{2}$$

which should not be a surprise as it is the middle of a uniform distribution from $1$ through to $\theta$.

Solving this for $\theta$ gives $\theta = 2 E[X] -1$ making the method of moments estimator $\hat \theta = 2 \bar X -1$

Comment: Thank you, Henry! You clarified perfectly, I really missed out that the distribution was discrete.